# SQL Server different select statement on same table and different result

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, web-applications

I have a products table that contains date-of-create, price, rate,.......   and multiple columns I need one select statement that returns the 10 newest records, 10 lowest prices and the top rated products as separated result of each other something like

```
(select top 10 from products Order By Date ASC ) as newest_list
(select top 10 from products Order By price DESC ) as price_list
(select top 10 from products Order By Rate ASC ) as rateList_list
```

where ( newest_list price_list rateList_list) are different table result

Which better way to approach that result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want `union all` . . . and a subquery:

```
select *
from ((select top 10 'newest' as which, p.*
       from products p
       Order By Date ASC
      ) union all
      (select top 10 'priciest', p.*
       from products p
       Order By price DESC
      ) union all
      (select top 10 'ratiest', p.*
       from products p
       Order By Rate ASC
      )
     ) p
```

If you don't want duplicates, you can use `union` or window functions:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (order by date desc) as seqnum_d,
             row_number() over (order by price desc) as seqnum_p,
             row_number() over (order by rate asc) as seqnum_r
      from p
     ) p
where seqnum_d <= 10 or seqnum_p <= 10 or seqnum_r <= 10;
```

Comment: can I ask you other questions I have two tables one for products and other for type let say,  so for 99% of time products have one type refer as a foreign key     let say the banana product has 'type'  => 9  refer to fruit  for example and     for 0.01% of data  require 2 types    so type => '8,8'  i know its not good for normalization    and I'm really not going to create a third table for that   what the better approach to achive that   Thanks and have great day

Comment: @hassanJ . . . new questions should be asked as *questions*, not *comments*.